# 200 Status...Error? But it works?...Angular

Tags: angular, http, logging, request

200 Status...Error? But it works?..., issue completed

Comment: That's between you and the creator of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this error because of the type of your response, i don't think that **it's a valid json**. if your http call returns a string you can try this to fix the issue

```
 return this.http.delete(baseUrl, { responseType: 'text' });
```